# Conditional compilation with ifndef and || doesn't catch second case

Tags: ios, objective-c, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to disable automated crash logs reports when one or both of two defines are set: `DEBUG` for our debug builds and `INTERNATIONAL` for the international builds. When I try to do that in the `#ifndef` case, however, I get the warning `Extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive` and running with `DEBUG` defined will trigger Crittercism.

```
#ifndef defined(INTERNATIONAL) || defined(DEBUG)
    // WE NEED TO REGISTER WITH THE CRITTERCISM APP ID ON THE CRITTERCISM WEB PORTAL
    [Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"hahayoudidntthinkidleavetherealonedidyou"];
#else
    DDLogInfo(@"Crash log reporting is unavailable in the international build");

    // Since Crittercism is disabled for international builds, go ahead and
    // registers our custom exception handler. It's not as good sadly
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
    DDLogInfo(@"Registered exception handler");
#endif
```

This truth table shows what I expect:

```
INTL defined | DEBUG defined | Crittercism Enabled
     F       |      F        |    T
     F       |      T        |    F
     T       |      F        |    F
     T       |      T        |    F
```

This worked before when it was just `#ifndef INTERNATIONAL`. I've also tried without the `defined(blah)` and with parentheses around the whole statement (same warning and an error respectively).

How do I get the behavior I want from the compiler?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want:

```
#if !defined(INTERNATIONAL) && !defined(DEBUG)
    // neither defined - setup Crittercism
#else
    // one or both defined
#endif
```

Or you can do:

```
#if defined(INTERNATIONAL) || defined(DEBUG)
    // one or both defined
#else
    // neither defined - setup Crittercism
#endif
```

Comment: This fixes it, thanks. Do you know if there's something about `#ifndef` that prevents complex conditionals?

Comment: You can't combine `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` with `defined()`. And `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` can only check a single value - `#ifndef INTERNATIONAL`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found one post [Conditional Compilation](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_078.HTM)  which can be better explained the differences between `#if`/`#elif` and `#ifdef`/`#ifndef`from syntax level:

- `#if constant-expression newline`
- `#ifdef identifier newline`
- `#ifndef identifier newline`
- `#else newline`
- `#elif constant-expression newline`
- `#endif newline`

So here we can see `#ifndef` must be followed by 'identifier', that was often the macro defined by `#define` directive, or @rmaddy said 'a single value'.

But `if` can be followed by 'constant-expression' so that the conditional expression `defined(INTERNATIONAL) || defined(DEBUG)` or `!defined(INTERNATIONAL) && !defined(DEBUG)` can be used.